# Cedilla In Properties Doesn't Get Read

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a very linguistic issue to solve. I'm creating a java spring boot application which has to support, among the other languages, french. So in the .properties file I've created for french I have a line similar to this:

`getstarted=commençons`

However, when shown in the HTML5 file the output is: commen�ons, with the question mark instead of the cedilla. Now, this application also supports japanese, so when I paste japanese-language text in the japanese .properties file it gets automatically escaped with unicode. I was wondering if someone could tell me how to properly escape the cedilla... all help is appreciated. Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing guys, the text in the properties file just had to be edited to:

getstarted=commen\u1E09\ons

Answer (score 0):

The way to read the `.properties` file is presumed to be the `Properties#load()` method. This method supports only Latin-1 (ASCII) characters, so you have to use `native2ascii` when a `.properties` file contains non-ASCII characters.

If running `native2ascii` bothers you, you can also use `Properties#loadFromXML()` and XML format file rather than line-oriented format `.properties` file. When you have `resources/prop.xml` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<entry key="Chinese">开始</entry>
<entry key="English">start</entry>
<entry key="French">commençons</entry>
<entry key="Japanese">はじめる</entry>
</properties>
```

and you can read it like this:

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try {
            props.loadFromXML(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/prop.xml"));
            System.out.println(props);
            // You will get "{English=start, French=commençons, Chinese=开始, Japanese=はじめる}"
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```